# Access GeoJSON-String with Esri REST-API in Android with Token

Tags: android, rest, security, geojson, esri

I have been stuggeling wiht that for a while and found no working solution:
I want to get a GeoJSON-String from an own ArcGIS Web Server. I want to use the REST-API and got it working in the browser. I just have to type in my username and password and after my authentification i can use the link to get the GeoJSON-String.
In Android I tried it with different solutions, one - of course - was to follow the instructions on the [Esri-Website](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/guide/working-with-secure-arcgis-services.htm#GUID-C14685DA-7CC8-4C07-8C2D-291CE13FAC62). Here they explain how to set the **Username** and the **Password** to create a *UserCredential*. The *UserCredential* now is passed to the Method to create a new *ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer* together with the REST-Link. So they get a new Layer, but there is no method, where you can pass the *UserCredential* and the *Link* to get just a String.
Because I want to get polygons I thought, that the [ArcGISFeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ags/ArcGISFeatureLayer.html) could help me out. But if I pass the given User-Informations and the Link i just get back an null-Objekt.

Here is a snippet of my most-hopefull code:

```
String url = "https://domain.de/arcgis/rest/services/FeatureEditor/FeatureEditor/FeatureServer/13/query?where=fahrzeug_id+%3D+21+AND+auftrag_revisionnewest+%3D+1+AND+auftrag_id+%3D+45&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&outSR=4326&returnDistinctValues=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnZ=false&returnM=false&f=geojson";
UserCredentials creds = new UserCredentials();
creds.setSSLRequired(true);
creds.setUserAccount("username", "password");
ArcGISFeatureLayer featureLayer = new ArcGISFeatureLayer(url,(ArcGISFeatureLayer.Options)null,creds);
```

So the best would be to get just the GeoJSON-String as accessable with the Link. But how can I access the HTTP with the *Username* and *Password*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that style of query within the ArcGIS Android SDK you'll have to do it with creating a FeatureLayer and then using the [Query](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/tasks/ags/query/Query.html) class to define the equivalent of your query string. This gives you back a FeatureSet that contains features which should have the information you're looking for, but it won't be in the form of GeoJSON. There's a toJSON method on the FeatureSet that might give you what you're looking for, but I'm not positive. If you just want a pure JSON response, you're going to have to do the HTTP requests yourself, setting up whatever authentication the REST API needs within your request and then handling the response.